# How to change the locale options in magento cloud sandbox environment?

Tags: magento-cloud

I am using the magento cloud sandbox to work.
And I want to change the locale information at the backend admin panel.
But the checkbox of locale options is locked and cannot be changed.
I think maybe it is because the cloud environment is the production mode,
so then I want to change the production mode to developer mode.
But it cannot be changed.

Is there anyone who can help?

Thank you so much.

Comment: you want to change admin locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simply run command on production mode with your desired locale.**

e.g for English(Australia)

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU -f
```

for English (United Kingdom)

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f
```

**Now you are able to select "English(Australia)" and "English (United Kingdom)" in locale dropdown.**

Note: In production mode it will work like that only. based on your pub/static available version it will show dropdown's options.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your answer. But unfortunately, even i installed the other language packages, and created a new store views the checkbox after locale is still locked. How can I unlock it??

Comment: have you exectuted above commands as per your need?